# Get checkbox value of datagrid column?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I have a datagrid in my web application with a checkbox in it using itemrenderer. How can i get the value of checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

Since itemRenderers can be recycled when a DataGrid is scrolled, you should tie the value of the checkbox to a value in your dataProvider. Then you can loop through the ArrayCollection and get all of the rows where `Selected==true`

**My data object:**

```
package 
{
  [Bindable]
  public class MyData
  {
    private var _name:String;
    private var _selected:Boolean;

    public function get Name():String { return _name; }
    public function set Name(value:String):void { _name = value; }

    public function get Selected():Boolean { return _selected; }
    public function set Selected(value:Boolean):void { _selected = value; }

  }
}
```

**My DataGrid:**

```
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{myArrayCollectionOfMyDataObjects}">
  <mx:columns>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="Name"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Selected" dataField="Selected">
      <mx:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
          <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" paddingLeft="2" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
            <mx:CheckBox id="chkSelected" change="{data.Selected = chkSelected.selected}" selected="{data.Selected}" />
          </mx:VBox>
        </fx:Component>
      </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>
  </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly with one exception. I got a compile error for having {} around the code for change. Removing the {} makes everything work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

```
If (CType(row.FindControl("chkEmailAlert"), CheckBox).Checked = True) Then
    Arr_EmailAlert(i) = "True"
Else
    Arr_EmailAlert(i) = "False"
End If
```

like this one more Class, called DirectCast will be there and by using the FindControl method we can find the id of the Control checkBox and the value also to use it.